# Read lines 2by 2 python

Tags: python

I want to read all lines from a file and store in a list, 2 by 2 elements until list finish iterating.

```
-Read first 2 lines from a list, and do stuff
-Continue reading more 2 lines, and do stuff
-Do so until whole list finish
```

Inside test.txt

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
gg
hh
```

- 

```
accounts_list = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    accounts_list = [line.strip() for line in f]

for acc in accounts_list:
    #do stuff with 2
    #continue reading more 2
    # do another stuff with the next 2
    # read until whole list finish
```

How i can do that, i can't make it.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re wanting to do. Could put more detail in your example?

Answer (score 2):

I think iterating through the indices by 2 steps `range(0, len(accounts_list), 2)` instead of list item of `accounts_list` should work

```
accounts_list = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    accounts_list = [line.strip() for line in f]

for i in range(0, len(accounts_list), 2):
    acc1 = accounts_list[i]
    acc2 = accounts_list[i + 1]
    #do stuff with 2
    #continue reading more 2
    # do another stuff with the next 2
    # read until whole list finish
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use an explicit iterator (instead of letting the `for` loop create its own), you can read two lines per iteration: one by the loop itself, the second in the body.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    itr = iter(f)

    for acc1 in itr:
        acc2 = next(itr)
        # Do stuff with acc1 and acc2
        # If the file has an odd number of lines,
        # you should wrap the assignment to acc2
        # in a try statement to catch the explicit StopIteration it will raise
```

I don't really like the asymmetry of reading the two lines in two different ways, so I would use an explicit `while` loop and use `next` to get both lines.

```
 with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    itr = iter(f)

    while True:
        try:
            acc1 = next(itr)
            acc2 = next(itr)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        # Do stuff with acc1 and acc2
```

Also, be sure to check the [recipe section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) of the `itertools` documentation for the `grouper` recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one reasonably idiomatic way of doing it. The key is the use of `zip(it, it)` (passing the same iterator twice), which causes `zip` to create a generator of tuples consisting of pairs of values from `it`. (A more general form of this idiom is documented under "tips and tricks" in the [Python documentation for `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)):

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    accounts_iter = (line.strip() for line in f)
    for first, second in zip(accounts_iter, accounts_iter):
       # Just an example
       print(f" First is '{first}'")
       print(f"Second is '{second}'")
```

That snippet does not create a list; it simply iterates over the input. Unless you need to keep the data for later use, there is no point in creating the list; it's simply a waste of memory (which could be a lot of memory if the file is large.) However, if you really wanted a list, for some reason, you could do the following:

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    accounts_iter = (line.strip() for line in f)
    accounts = [*zip(accounts_iter, accounts_iter)]
```

That will create a list of tuples, each tuple containing two consecutive lines.

Two other notes:

1. This only works with iterators (which includes generators); not with iterable containers. You need to turn an iterable container into an iterator using the `iter` built-in function (as is done in the example in the Python docs).
2. `zip` stops when the *shortest* iterator finishes. So if your file has an odd number of lines, the above will ignore the last line. If you would prefer to see an error if that happens, you can use the `strict=True` keyword argument to `zip` (again, as shown in the documentation). If, on the other hand, you'd prefer to have the loop run anyway, even with some missing lines, you could use `itertools.zip_longest` instead of `zip`.

Comment: Nice, I forgot about the trick of passing the same iterator as two arguments to `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

To store file in a nested list "2 by 2 elements":

code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    accounts_list = [[acc0.strip(), acc1.strip()] for acc0, acc1 in zip(f, f)]
```

output:

```
[['aa', 'bb'], ['cc', 'dd'], ['ee', 'ff'], ['gg', 'hh']]
```

then you can iterate over on this list to work with